# Replace 2D numpy array with 3D (elements to vectors)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, opencv

This question has probably been asked before so I'm happy to be pointed to the answer but I couldn't find it.

I have a 2D numpy array of `True` and `False`. Now I need to convert it into a black and white image (a 3D numpy array), that is, I need [0,0,0] in place of every `False` and [1,1,1] in place of every `True`. What's the best way to do this? For example,

```
Input:

[[False, True],
 [True, False]]

Output:
[[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]],
 [[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]]]
```

(As you probably know, 3D images are arrays of shape `(height, width, 3)` where 3 is the depth dimension i.e. number of channels.)

Bonus points if someone can tell me how to also convert it back, i.e., if I have a pure black and white image (purely [0,0,0] and [0,0,1] pixels), how do I get a 2D matrix of the same height-width dimensions but with `True` in place of white pixels ([1,1,1]) and `False` in place of black pixels ([0,0,0]).

Comment: `a = a.astype(np.uint8)` for the 3D you can use either `np.expand_dims(arr, axis=2)` or `np.stack([list of 2D arrays], axis=2)`, for the `True-False` you can use `np.where(arr==1)`

Comment: @Bilal. None of those are great options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cheapest way is to view your `bool` data as `np.uint8`, and add a fake dimension:

```
img = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(mask.view(np.uint8),
                                      strides=mask.strides + (0,),
                                      shape=mask.shape + (3,))
```

Unlike [`mask.astype(np.uint8)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html), [`mask.view(np.uint8)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) does not copy the data, instead harnesses the fact that `bool_` is stored in a single byte. Similarly, the new dimension created by [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) is a view which does not copy any data.

You can bypass `as_strided` and `view` by creating a new [array object](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) manually:

```
img = np.ndarray(shape=mask.shape + (3,), dtype=np.uint8,
                 strides=mask.strides + (0,), buffer=mask)
```

Comment: Thank you!! Any suggestions how to go the other way (you have `img` as you called it, and want `mask`)?

Comment: @VainmondeDeCourtenay. You can do `img[..., 0].view(bool)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the clearest way is this:

```
a = np.array([[False, True], [True, False]])
out = np.zeros((*a.shape, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
out[a.nonzero()] = 1

>>> out
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0]]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: You can do `a` instead of `a.nonzero()`. `a` is already a boolean mask. No need to convert it to indices for a one-off operation.